# Monotouch/Xamarin Binding Inheritance

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to implement a monotouch binding for FastPDFKit. I'm having trouble with an inherited constructor. I'm trying to bind "ReaderViewController" from fastPDFKit. ReaderViewController inherits from MFDocumentViewController which inherits from UIViewController.

My C#

```
NSUrl fullURL = new NSUrl (fullPath);
FastPDFKitBinding.MFDocumentManager DocManager = new FastPDFKitBinding.MFDocumentManager (fullURL);

DocManager.EmptyCache ();


//line where the errors occur
FastPDFKitBinding.ReaderViewController pdfView = new FastPDFKitBinding.ReaderViewController (DocManager); 
pdfView.DocumentID = PageID.ToString ();

Source.PView.PresentViewController(pdfView, true, null);
```

This code does not build, giving me two errors when I make the new ReaderViewController:

```
Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `FastPDFKitBinding.ReaderViewController.ReaderViewController(MonoTouch.Foundation.NSCoder)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (iOSFlightOpsMobile)

Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `FastPDFKitBinding.MFDocumentManager' expression to type `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSCoder' (CS1503) (iOSFlightOpsMobile)
```

The relevant part of my binding

```
namespace FastPDFKitBinding
{
    [BaseType (typeof (UIAlertViewDelegate))]
    interface MFDocumentManager {

        [Export ("initWithFileUrl:")]
        IntPtr Constructor (NSUrl URL);

        [Export ("emptyCache")]
        void EmptyCache ();

        [Export ("release")]
        void Release ();
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (UIViewController))]
    interface MFDocumentViewController {
        [Export ("initWithDocumentManager:")]
        IntPtr Constructor (MFDocumentManager docManager);

        [Export ("documentId")]
        string DocumentID { get; set; }

        [Export ("documentDelegate")]
        NSObject DocumentDelegate { set; }
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (MFDocumentViewController))]
    interface ReaderViewController {

    }
}
```

Now, I can get rid of the errors by taking the binding Exports from MFDocumentViewController and putting them in my ReaderViewController Interface.

```
    [BaseType (typeof (UIViewController))]
interface MFDocumentViewController {

}

[BaseType (typeof (MFDocumentViewController))]
interface ReaderViewController {
    [Export ("initWithDocumentManager:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (MFDocumentManager docManager);

    [Export ("documentId")]
    string DocumentID { get; set; }

    [Export ("documentDelegate")]
    NSObject DocumentDelegate { set; }
}
```

But I don't want to do this, because those constructors/methods are defined in MFDocumentViewController. How can I get the binding to correctly use those inherited methods/constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fix is the correct implementation.

Ctor inheritance in .NET (and probably all OO languages) require the base ctor to be defined. Let me give an example.

This works fine

```cs
class A {
    public A (string m) {}
}

class B : A{
    public B (string m) : base (m) {}
}

class C : B {
    public C (string m) : base (m) {}
}
```

When you do `new C("hello")`, the ctor for A, then B, then C is executed with the parameter.

This does not work:

```cs
class A {
    public A (string m) {}
}

class B : A {
    public B () : base ("empty") {}
}

class C : B {
    public C (string m) : base (m) {}
}
```

The reason is the compiler does have to call the B ctor (as C inherit from it) but doesn't know which ctor to use.

So, when binding an obj-C library for monotouch, make sure you re-declare all the constructors that might need to be called at some point.

Comment: Thank you Stephane for the examples/explanation.