# Xamarin iOS Binding: Could not initialise an instance of the type, returned nil

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've bound an iOS library, [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit), to C# using Xamarin/Monotouch. [After some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947923/issues-linking-objc-library-using-xamarin) I've managed to get the library to build ok.

My code can be found here: https://github.com/jamesmundy/SVGKit.Xamarin

Unfortunately, when I try to initialise a type from the class I receive the following error:

> Could not initialize an instance of the type
>   'SVGKitBindings.SVGKFastImageView': the native 'init' method returned
>   nil. It is possible to ignore this condition by setting
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

The full stack trace is can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/jamesmundy/15184b9dbe29639295d5).

Any idea as to what is causing this problem and what I can do to rectify it?

**Update:** Here is the full Build Output of my project. http://pastebin.com/f60wFm52

**Update 2:** Tried setting SmartLink to false and rebuilding, same error though a slightly different build output. http://pastebin.com/ApCAz2BP

Comment: Most likely the native library wasn't properly linked in the app. Can you pastebin a complete build log?

Comment: Thanks Rolf, I've done that now. http://pastebin.com/f60wFm52

Comment: Try changing to `SmartLink = false` in the LinkWith attribute.

Comment: Changed that and rebuilt, no change unfortunately. A slightly different build output though: http://pastebin.com/4if7XCDk

Comment: Could it be something to do the with Frameworks and Linker flags SVGKit requires (CoreText, CoreImage, CoreGraphics, QuartzCore, UIKit, libxml2.dylib) and a linker flag of "-ObjC"?

Comment: That change didn't cause the solution to rebuild; try cleaning it first.

Comment: I cleaned all and then rebuilt. Still no joy unfortunately: http://pastebin.com/ApCAz2BP

Comment: Try adding "--registrar:static" to the additional mtouch arguments in the (main) project's iOS Build and see if anything changes.

Comment: I already tried that unfortunately, it said that registrar arguments weren't allowed in a unified API project. Thanks for helping me out with this - very baffling.

Comment: Those arguments are allowed - what exactly did the error message say?

Comment: Ah, I tried again - I think I got confused with something else I tried (legacystatic). Unfortunately that still didn't work - made sure I cleaned + rebuilt it this time. http://pastebin.com/j6ne1Jru

Comment: I've continued to look at this over the weekend but still no luck unfortunately, any idea where I can go from here? Could this be a bug with Xamarin?

Comment: Can you add a test project that reproduces the error to the github repo?

Comment: Ok, will do that now.

Comment: That's done now. I added an example project to git that demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/jamesmundy/SVGKit.Xamarin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the source code for SVGKFastImageView init [1]:

```
- (id)init
{
    NSAssert(false, @"init not supported, use initWithSVGKImage:");

    return nil;
}
```

The managed exception is correct: you can't call this constructor.

[1] https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/blob/cd47ae95e57c9490a9238173855ecbe83d4aaf44/Source/UIKit%20additions/SVGKFastImageView.m#L53

Comment: I should have definitely looked there before this - thanks. However, although FastImageView and LayeredImageView both inherit from ImageView they don't have the constructors they should have - the only available constructors are empty and NSCoder - there should be a constructor accepting an SVGKImage.

Comment: Looks like I will have to redeclare constructors:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794490/monotouch-xamarin-binding-inheritance. Thanks for your help!